# Spliting a list into sublists based on an element containing a string

Tags: python, string, list, element, sublist

I know there is a simple solution but I can't seem to find it.

I want to split a list based on an element just containing a string.

In this case "Store"

```
from itertools import groupby

test_string = ['Store465', 'Steve', '145658', '125', 'Brad', '457958', '200', 'Store678', 'John', '30122', '898', '123', 'O', 'Joe', '36789', '123', 'U', ' 456']

# I've tried 

test_string[:] = [x for x in test_string if "Store" not in x]

print(test_string)

# but that will just remove the  Store elements

# ['Steve', '145658', '125', 'Brad', '457958', '200', 'John', '30122', '898', '123', 'O', 'Joe', '36789', '123', 'U', ' 456']

# and

test_result = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(test_string,lambda x:x if "Store" not in x) if not k]

# This creates an error. 
#
#   File "<input>", line 13
#     test_result = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(test_string,lambda x:x if "Store" not in x) if not k]
#                                                                                         ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've been on stackoverflow and google trying to find the correct syntax or process with no luck. My desired output would be

```
[['Store465', 'Steve', '145658', '125', 'Brad', '457958', '200'], ['Store678', 'John', '30122', '898', '123', 'O', 'Joe', '36789', '123', 'U', ' 456']]
```

Comment: What exactly do you want `lambda x:x if "Store" not in x` to *mean*? What should the result of the `lambda` be when `"Store"` is contained in `x`? What should the result be when it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the lists by the occurrence of `Store` in the list you could do something like this:

```
test_string = ['Store465', 'Steve', '145658', '125', 'Brad', '457958', '200', 'Store678', 'John', '30122', '898', '123', 'O', 'Joe', '36789', '123', 'U', ' 456']

test_loop = []
for item in test_string:
    if 'Store' in item: # create a new list to store all of the elements after store mentioned inside of the outer list
        test_loop.append([item])
    else:  # add elements after store into the last list and before the next mention of Store
        test_loop[-1].append(item)
print(test_loop)
```

which gives:

```
[['Store465', 'Steve', '145658', '125', 'Brad', '457958', '200'], ['Store678', 'John', '30122', '898', '123', 'O', 'Joe', '36789', '123', 'U', ' 456']]
```

Comment: This works. Thank you so much.